# Overriding scrolling method of ScrollView for handling horizontal sliding events

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to override the scrolling method (I don't know which function it uses to handle scrolling) of **ScrollView** so that an **EditText** (with vertical Scrollbar) inside it will scroll vertically only when change of y coordinate (for sliding the finger/pointer) is greater. And if the change of x coordinate is greater another function will be called.

How can I do it? Here is a code structure for clarification.

```
@Override
public void scrollerFunction(aListener){
    public void actionPerformed(params)
        if(abs(startY-EndY) >= abs(startX-EndX))
            //scrollUp or scrollDown
        else
            anotherFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ScrollingMovementMethod()` and set to your `EditText` using `setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())`.

```
yourEditText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod(){
    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event){
        //use MotionEvent to get touch position for your logic
    }
});
```

> I didn't test the code yet but it should give some idea to your problem.

**Update**

This code for `ScrollVview` which `EditText` inside it.

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

  @Override
  public void onScrollChanged() {
    //example
    if(abs(scrollView.getScrollY()-EndY)  >= abs(scrollView.getScrollX()-EndX) ){
      //scrollUp or scrollDown
    }else{
      anotherFunction();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `onScrollChanged` method.

You can try this --->

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged (int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt){
   // l Current horizontal scroll origin.
   // t Current vertical scroll origin.
   // oldl  Previous horizontal scroll origin.
   // oldt  Previous vertical scroll origin.
   if(abs(oldt-t) >= abs(oldl-l))
     //scrollUp or scrollDown
   else
     anotherFunction();
}
```

Give it a try. I don't know if it works.

[Source](http://bit.ly/1KQJq9M)